# Turtle Code from the Python website not working

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Okay, went over to Python.com and loaded up this page 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html for Turtle Coding basics.

[Right there they have a code that makes a red and yellow star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WbGX.png)

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

Well, I tried this code myself, and it doesn't work.  I get an error message saying ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined on line 2

Am I missing something?  I'm running Python 3.6 I believe.  I gotta say, it does not inspire a lot of confidence when something from the Python website doesn't seem to work...

UPDATE

Well, I spoke to the teachers at my Python class and apparently the "Python" program we're using is slightly different than actual Python.  I'm not sure but I think they said it's emulated through Javescript.or some such.  So, I had to add more basic stuff like "import turtle",  name a turtle, etc.

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen
mark=turtle.Turtle()
mark.color('red', 'yellow')
mark.begin_fill()
while True:
    mark.forward(100)
    mark.left(170)
    if abs(mark.xpos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

When I run this program, it draws one line, turns the Turtle and says, “AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'xpos' on line 9”

Comment: The code you provided runs as-is under Python3 and Python2 on my system.  The error message you quoted seems most frequently associated with JavaScript, not Python -- can you provide a transcript of your execution of the code including the resulting error message?

Comment: Does this help?
http://i.imgur.com/pK3qc3d.jpg

Comment: I looked at your page image and looked into ActiveCode.  It supports both Python and JavaScript (and other languages) and uses tags like `language: python` which expand to `<textarea data-component="activecode" data-language="python">` to indicate how to interpret the text of the code.  I'm still guessing your example is being mistakenly interpreted as JavaScript but I don't have a ready answer on how to fix that.  Check your ActiveCode documentation.  Or run the code at the command line and bypass ActiveCode for this example.

Comment: Well, I spoke to the teachers at my Python class and apparently the "Python" program we're using is slightly different than actual Python.  I'm not sure but I think they said it's emulated through Javescript.or some such.

Comment: Are you sure you can run turtle code in the browser like that?

Answer (score 0):

> “AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'xpos'

Read [the `turtle` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#tell-turtle-s-state). You have `pos()` method, which returns a `Vec2D` object.

No mention of  `xpos`

Maybe you want `xcor` for x - coordinate